# Implicit conversion from true value to std::true_type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

This is a simple template progs that I wrote to study C++:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T foo(T t, true_type)
{
    cout << t << " is integral! ";
    return 2 * t;
}


template<typename T>
T foo(T t, false_type)
{
    cout << t << " ain't integral! ";
    return -1 * (int)t;
}

template<typename T>
T do_foo(T t){
    return foo(t, is_integral<T>());
}

int main()
{
    cout << do_foo<int>(3) << endl;
    cout << do_foo<float>(2.5) << endl;
}
```

It doesn't do anything to fancy, but it does compile and work.

I am wondering how does the part `is_integral<T>()` work?

I was reading this : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral and I can't find any specific description of this behavior - no definition of `operator()`

Comment: It's not calling `operator()`, it's constructing a temporary, just like `int()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`is_integral<T>` is a type that inherits either from `true_type` or `false_type`.

`is_integral<T>()` is a constructor call, so that an instance of one of those types is an argument to the call to `foo`. The overload is then selected according to which one it is.

Comment: Note: to avoid confusion, in C++11 this could be `is_integral<T>{}`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. any pointer why they added that new notation? `()` notations seems more like creating an instance than `{}` which looks like definition.

Comment: @dashesy: Among other things, to deal with the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) issue. It also allowed the revision of initialization rules without breaking backward compatibility (on types conversions).